# Buggy toggle div in jQuery, jumping, not smooth

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Im trying to build a jquery solution to the work section on this website [www.hellomonday.com](http://www.hellomonday.com).

Ive built it so the image changes on hover, and when the div expands only if you see it in action it seems very jumpy and jutters, especially if I have more than 1 row of work on my site.

The image you see at the top, Id like to change on hover, when clicked and the div expands, I want the image to sort of grow with my div in height, and fade into the 3rd image (you will understand when seeing demo). If clicked again, the image should fade out into the first image and scale down accordingly.

**DEMO**

http://jsfiddle.net/fRfd4/1/

```
// On work showcase click, expand area to show information
    $('.work-showcase').click(function(){
        if ( !$(this).hasClass('active') ){
            $(this).addClass('active');
            $(this).find('ul li').animate({height:'350px'}, 500);
            $(this).find('ul li').css({
                'background':'url("http://www.placekitten.com/502/135")'
            });         
            $(this).find('ul li img').animate({height:'350px'}, 500);
            $(this).animate({height:'650px'}, 500,function() {  
                $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(this).offset().top });  
            });
        } else { 
            //return false;
            $(this).removeClass('active');
            $(this).find('ul li').animate({height:'120px'}, 500);
            $(this).find('ul li').css({
                'background':'url("http://www.placekitten.com/500/135")'
            });         
            $(this).find('ul li img').animate({height:'120px'}, 500);
            $(this).animate({height:'130px'}, 500);  
        };
    });
```

Can anybody think of a better way to build this?

Comment: Doesn't seem that bad to me. What browser are you using? One suggestion that may or may not have any effect is to either chain your calls, or cache your jQuery objects. You keep forcing it to search again for `$(this).find('ul li')`. Do it once and cache the result.

Comment: Sorry @MattBurland im not the best with jQuery so Im unsure how you would cache that haha

Comment: `var mystuff = $(this).find('ul li')`. Then you can do `mystuff.animate(...` and `mystuff.css(...`

Comment: @Liam Read here to help you out with your jQuery coding http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery/info